# Are Free Groups the "Smallest Group" Containing their Generators

Tags: soft-question, terminology, free-groups, universal-algebra, universal-property

I apologize if this is a duplicate; I was not sure how to search for this.

When I say "*the* smallest group" I mean unique up to isomorphism of course.

Specifically, is "the smallest group containing its generators" an intuitive way of interpreting the [universal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group#Universal_property) given on Wikipedia? The homomorphism $\varphi$ being an "embedding" of sorts?

[image]

With set systems, for example $\sigma-$algebras or topologies, whenever we say "the X generated by S" we usually mean equivalently "the smallest X containing S" (in some sense).

So essentially my question is this: is the intuition which is valid for set systems extensible to the thinking behind free algebraic objects?

Or at least to free groups, since the intersection of two groups is again a group, the same way the intersection of two topologies is a topology or the intersection of two $\sigma-$algebras is a $\sigma-$algebra.

Comment: All cyclic groups are generated by one element only. Among these, the free group is in fact the largest group by cardinality. But the others are only smaller because the generator meets a relation ...

Comment: I don't know about "smallest", but I literally think of a free group as the "free-est" group with respect to those generators. To be more precise, it is the group which is "free-est of relations" in the sense that the only relations that hold are relations which are forced to hold by the group theoretic axioms themselves.

Comment: If you put relations on the generators, things get smaller not bigger.

Comment: They are the largest, and the map is a quotient, not an embedding.

Comment: The free groups are small in the sense that they don't have any elements which aren't generated by your generating set, but large in the sense that all of the things generated by your generating set are different from each other.

Comment: Just to confirm, the above comments together imply that all relations which hold for groups which do not follow immediately from the group axioms can be expressed as quotients? Since every group is the quotient of some free group by the universal property for free groups, and every relation implies a homomorphism and the kernel thereof? (e.g. $x^7 = a \implies (x^7)^{-1}a, a(x^7)^{-1}, x^7 a^{-1}, a^{-1}x^7 \in \operatorname{Ker}$[some homomorphism])

Comment: @William Yeah. If you have a group expressed in terms of generators and relations (a.k.a. a presentation of a group) for example $G=\left\langle a,b,c|ab^2,c^3,a^7c\right\rangle$ then if you let $F_{\{a,b,c\}}$ be the free group on $\{a,b,c\}$ and $N(ab^2,c^3,a^7c)$ be the smallest normal subgroup of $F_{\{a,b,c\}}$ containing $ab^2$, $c^3$ and $a^7c$, then $G\simeq F_{\{a,b,c\}}/N(ab^2,c^3,a^7c)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you have things backwards: as the comments indicate, $F_S$ is in a sense the $\textit{largest}$ group for a given set of generators. If $S$ the set of generators for a group $G$, the map from $F_S \to G$ is surjective and hence any group $G$ may be identified with a quotient of $F_S$.

If by "smallest" you mean least structure, then this is correct as we have no relations.